# Http basic auth with nginx on different port

Tags: nginx, webserver, .htpasswd

I've got a website with a reverse front-end proxy in which my app listens on port 3000. I've got another app that sits on 3001 which is part of the same directory that serves the contents for the site on port 3000.

What I want to do.

Anyone going to `mydomain.com:3001` would be prompted for `auth_basic` credentials. Anyone going to `mydomain.com` would get through normally.

My current nginx config:

```
upstream app_example {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
      keepalive 64;
}

server {
      root /var/www/example;
      listen 0.0.0.0:80;
      server_name example.com example;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/app_example.log;
}
```

Would it be something like this?

```
upstream app_tools {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com example;

        location / {
        auth_basic      "secured site tools";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/example/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://app_tools;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create different `server` for `mydomain.com:3001` and `mydomain.com`

```
upstream app_tools {
      server 127.0.0.1:3000;
      keepalive 64;
}


server {
      root /var/www/example;
      listen 0.0.0.0:80;
      server_name mydomain.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/app_example.log;
      location / {
            proxy_pass http://app_tools;
      }  
}


server {
      root /var/www/example;
      listen 0.0.0.0:3001;
      server_name mydomain.com;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/app_example_secure.log;
      location / {
            auth_basic      "secured site tools";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/example/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://app_tools;
      }  
}
```

But remember what security through obscurity - bad idea.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks -- that seemed to work! I'm using kue.js (https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue/blob/master/lib/http/index.js) and it binds to a specific port when using the webapp, so I'm just trying to put some type of protection in front of it so you can't actively browse the taskworker queue. Binding to the same port of my application would be extremely sloppy since I'd need to import my routes and middleware and make sure I don't re-use any of the namespaced routes that kue has (plus I hate editing libraries directly).